# C++ overloading: operator+ for adding Matrices by element

Tags: c++, matrix, operators, operator-overloading, addition

I am trying to overload the "+" operator for a Matrix program. Here's my code, it looks OK to me. But when i add two matrices in my main-function nothing happens. 
Can someone help?
thanks :)

btw:

-The program compiles and runs just fine up until the point where it should add to Matrices.

-I assume there's problem is in the implementation of my operator+()-function, because i have copied the code into an add(Mtrx,Mtrx) function to test and it didn't work either.

//Mtrx.h

```
#ifndef MTRX_H_
#define MTRX_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::ostream;

class Mtrx {
    int lines,cols;
    float **p;
public:

    Mtrx();
    Mtrx(int,int);
    int getLines();
    int getCols();
    float getElement(int,int);
    void setLines(int);
    void setCols(int);
    void setElement(int,int,float);

    Mtrx operator+(Mtrx&);

        ~Mtrx();
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Mtrx& m);

#endif /* MTRX_H_ */
```

//Mtrx.cpp

```
//...
//...
Mtrx::~Mtrx(){
delete p;
p = NULL;
}

Mtrx Mtrx::operator+(Mtrx& m){
if(this->getLines() == m.getLines() && this->getCols() == m.getCols()){
    Mtrx res(getLines(),getCols());

    for (int i = 1; i <= this->getLines(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= this->getCols(); j++){
            res.setElement(i,j,(this->getElement(i,j)+m.getElement(i,j)));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your iterations from `1..nLines` and `1..nCols` looks suspicious.  Is this intentional or did you mean to start from zero?

Comment: Can you paste your main() as well? operator+ looks OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a destructor but you're missing a copy constructor and an assignment operator. As a rule of thumb if you have any of them you should have all of them.

```
Mtrx(const Mtrx&);
Mtrx& operator=(const Mtrx&);
~Mtrx();
```

Without an explicit copy constructor the compiler will generate one for you. It's not smart, though, so it doesn't know to allocate new memory for `p` when it copies a matrix. It just copies the pointer, resulting in the original matrix and the copy both referring to the same memory. Both of them will call `delete p` when their destructor runs which is bad news bears for the second guy.

This is exactly what happens when `operator+` returns and `res` is copied.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be exaclty the problem. I am a C++ beginner, so I am having difficulties implementing the Rule of Three. After hours and hours I established that my new assignment operator and destrucor are working but my copy constructor still doesn't. :(
 
`Mtrx::Mtrx(const Mtrx& m){
    cout<<"Copy Constructor called!"<<endl;
    lines = m.lines;
    cols = m.cols;
    p = new float*[lines];
    for(int i = 0; i < m.lines; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++){
 cout<<"Copy constructor reached this point."<< endl;
 p[i][j] = m.p[i][j]; 
 //dsnt reach here.
  }
 }
    }`

Comment: sorry about the formatting, I'm worse at that than I am at C++.

Answer (score 1):

Check your braces. You either are missing one, or your control path for the if(false) isn't returning.

```
Mtrx Mtrx::operator+(Mtrx& m){
if(this->getLines() == m.getLines() && this->getCols() == m.getCols()){
    Mtrx res(getLines(),getCols());

    for (int i = 1; i <= this->getLines(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= this->getCols(); j++){
            res.setElement(i,j,(this->getElement(i,j)+m.getElement(i,j)));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```